# How to set Min/Max for date picker in KendoDateTimePicker using AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, datetimepicker

I'm working with a kendo grid which has a datetimepicker as a column in every row.

**The datetimepicker should only allow user to pick yesterday's and today's dates and time is flexible.**

I've tried in many ways but I'm not able to get it done.

**My grid columns are-**

```js
 { field: "Fac", title: "Fac Name", width: "100px", editor: $scope.facDropDownEditor, template: "#=(FacFacyName==null)? '' : Fac.FacName #" },
          { field: "RecordedDate", title: "Date - Time", format: "{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm}", editor: dateTimeEditor, width: "100px" },
          { field: "Remarks",title:"Remarks",width:"120px"},
        { field: "Volume", title: "Volume", width: "100px" },
    {
        command: [
           {
               name: "edit", title: "Edit", "template": "<a class='k-button k-grid-edit' href='' style='min-width:40px;' title=\"Edit\"><span class='k-icon k-i-edit'></span></a>"
           },
        ], field: "Actions",title:"Actions", width: "60px"
    }
```

**My datetimeEditor is-**

```js
function dateTimeEditor(container, options) {
    $('<input data-text-field="' + options.field + '" data-value-field="' + options.field + '" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '" data-format="' + options.format + '"/>')
            .appendTo(container)
            .kendoDateTimePicker({});
}
```

How to edit datepicker so that I get only today's and yesterday's dates selectable

Comment: Take a look here:
http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/datepicker/disable-dates
Reverse that, so you can only select the defined ones, should be simple enough having an array of selectable dates.

Comment: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/editors/datepicker/how-to/AngularJS/range-selection . I hope you can use the k-min and k-max as per the example.

Comment: max date is working fine, but I'm not able to get mindate as yesterday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope this will help!

```
function dateTimeEditor(container, options) {
        $('<input data-text-field="' + options.field + '" data-value-field="' + options.field + '" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '" data-format="' + options.format + '"/>')
                .appendTo(container)
                .kendoDateTimePicker({
                     max:new Date();//todays day
                     var yestarday= new Date();
                     yestarday.setDate(dt.getDate() - 1);
                     min:yestarday;//yestardays date
             });
}
```

Comment: There is something wrong with the syntax, it gives errors while typing that code

Comment: `kendoDateTimePicker({  

                     max:new Date(),   

                     //var yestarday= new Date();    

                     //yestarday.setDate(dt.getDate() - 1);    
                     //min:yestarday;    
             });`   

min date works in this way